# Magento API throws an exception on successful login

Tags: c#, api, magento, exception, soap

In C# when connecting to the Magento API, it is throwing an excepion on successful login:

```
// connect to the first store
_magentoService = new MagentoService {Url = "http://store1.com/index.php/api/v2_soap"};
_magentoService.login(user1, password1);

// later on, connect to the second store (note the different url)
_magentoService = new MagentoService {Url = "http://store2.com/index.php/api/v2_soap"};
_magentoService.login(user2, password2);
```

Connecting to the first store returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:loginResponse><loginReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">bec0144c8642f227e8fb3d032f40xxxx</loginReturn></ns1:loginResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Which is exact response expected for a successful login.  Connecting to the second store also returns the exact same result AND also throws an exception:

```
  System.Net.WebException was caught
  Message=The request failed with the error message:
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:loginResponse><loginReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">bec0144c8642f227e8fb3d032f40zzzz</loginReturn></ns1:loginResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
  Source=System.Web.Services
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
       at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

Why is it that throws an exception, when the login was successful?  The first site (successful) is Magento v1.6 and the store that is failing is Magento v1.7

I am using Magento via a web reference, and the generated code for the login() method is below.  The exception occurs on the call to this.Invoke:

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerAction", RequestNamespace="urn:Magento", ResponseNamespace="urn:Magento")]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("loginReturn")]
public string login(string username, string apiKey) {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("login", new object[] {
                username,
                apiKey});
    return ((string)(results[0]));
}
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/csharlibformagexmlrpcapi/ give this a try, or maybe it will give you some insight on successfully connecting. Magento's API isn't the greatest, especially with anything not PHP native.

Comment: I am getting the exact same error. By using Fiddler and capturing the HTTP Response I see that the only difference between the logins is that one is coming back with: HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily. Since there is no Location header the SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse() raises an exception. I don't have a fix yet but I think it may have to do with how the web service is configured in Apache.